# Ocultar en el Segmentador de datos de Excel el campo (en blanco)

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una tabla del cual he creado varias tablas dinámicas y estás tablas se filtran por el campo "`FECHA_REALIZACION"` y "`FECHA_RESOLUCION`".
He sacado un segmentador de datos para poder filtrar las fechas

[image: Segmentador]

Lo que pasa es que como en mi campo tanto fecha realización y resolución tengo celdas en blanco, abajo del listado en mi segmentador de fechas aparece el registro "(en blanco)" lo cual tiene sentido, pero no quiero que aparezca eso.

¿Existe alguna función o opción en la configuración del segmentador de datos para ocultar esto? He probado la de "Ocultar elementos sin datos": esta al parece solo te quita aquellas celdas cuyos datos han sido borrados (vacíos) y no los que vienen de origen en "blanco", tampoco puedo borrar las filas en blanco, ya que aunque no tiene datos en esta columna sí viene registros en las otras demás 10 columnas de la tabla.

He probado a usar macros para poner los campos "en blanco" sin datos, para tenerlo en el segmentador como sin datos, pero me salta error.

Este es el código:

```
Sub AsignarSinDatos()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabla_Datos") ' Reemplaza "NombreHoja" con el nombre de tu hoja de datos
    Set rng = ws.Range("FECHA_REALIZACION") ' Reemplaza "FECHA_REALIZACION" con la referencia a tu columna de fechas
    
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Value = "Sin datos"
        End If
    Next cell End Sub
```

Y me da error sección `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabla_Datos")`, dice

> error 9, subíndice fuera de intervalo.

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué es FECHA_REALIZACION? ¿Qué es Tabla_Datos?

En `Set rng = ws.Range("FECHA_REALIZACION")` define el rango de tú columna, por ejemplo: `Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A50")`

Asegúrate de que Tabla_Datos es el nombre de la hoja donde están los datos. Con este código debería funcionarte:

```
Sub AsignarSinDatos()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabla_Datos") ' Reemplaza "NombreHoja" con el nombre de tu hoja de datos
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A50")
    
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "" Then cell.Value = "Sin datos"            
    Next  
End Sub
```